# Meaning of has been to my house several times and has not been to my house

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the difference between:

> David **has been** to my house several times.
>
> David **has not been** to my house.

Answer (score 1):

> David has been to my house several times

David visited your house in the past many times

> David has not been to my house

David has never visited your house (when this sentence is used out of context)